# Create a Redirect which adds logged in user's username to website url in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to add a manual redirect such that logged in user can be redirect to [www.my-site.com/username](http://www.my-site.com/username)   from   [www.my-site.com/media-portal](http://www.my-site.com/media-portal)
(where username is that of logged in user.)

How to create this redirect in WordPress. Can you mention php to add

Answer (score 0):

Guys is this code right to add in functions.php?

```
function media_portal_redirect(){

         <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
         $current_user = wp_get_current_user();   
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $current_user->user_login ) );  
        exit();  
}        
   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'media_portal_redirect' );
```